# Error -Route not defined in view-> Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, routes

I have given a view URL as

```
<input type="hidden" id="urlview" urlview="{{ URL::route('Batch-InnerView/'.$batch->batch_id) }}" /> in view and my web route is 
Route::get('/Batch-InnerView/{id}',['as' => 'BatchInnerView', 'uses' => 'student\StudentBatchController@getView']);
```

showing error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Route [/Batch-InnerView/1] not defined. (View: D:\vjcetcrm\resources\views\settings\student\Batch-InnerView.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Your route action put like this**

```
urlview="{{ route('BatchInnerView',$batch->batch_id) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be as below.

```
{{ route('BatchInnerView',$batch->batch_id) }}
```

And if you want to call it as URL then.

```
{{ url('Batch-InnerView/'.$batch->batch_id) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate yourself, try to write a sort code and clean code. You can try this
Change this

```
Route::get('/Batch-InnerView/{id}',['as' => 'BatchInnerView', 'uses' => 'student\StudentBatchController@getView']);
```

To this

```
Route::get('/Batch-InnerView/{id}','student\StudentBatchController@getView')->name('BatchInnerView');
```

In your view just call it with

```
{{route('BatchInnerView',['id'=>$batch->batch_id])}}
```